# Why don't we speak of medial and lateral rotation of the forearm? And pronation and supination of the upper arm?

Tags: human-anatomy, terminology

Why don't we speak of medial and lateral rotation of the forearm?

I notice we speak of forearm supination and forearm pronation, but why not medial and lateral rotation.

It seems to me that if we take the diagram of the human with palms forward, which I understand to be the neutral position one is meant to start from.. then forearm pronation looks to me like a medial movement. So why not medial rotation?

And similarly with upper arm.. why don't we speak of pronation and supination of the upper arm?  We speak of medial and lateral rotation of it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pronation and supination involve a **change in relationship between the ulna and radius.**

> When you rotate your hand from palm ventrally (as in anatomical
>   position) to palm facing dorsally you have moved your hand from a
>   supinated position to a pronated one. This movement of supination to
>   pronation occurs when *the distal head of the radius rotates on the
>   capitulum , the bone rotates along its long axis, and the proximal
>   head of the radius flips over the ulna.* *([Duke Medicine](https://web.duke.edu/anatomy/mbs/Lab11_MBS/Lab12_preLab.html))*

and:

> Pronation and supination are rotational motions that exist exclusively
>   in the forearm. The mechanical bases for these movements are the
>   existence of two forearm bones and the presence of two coupled
>   trochoid joints—the proximal and distal radioulnar joints (PRUJ and
>   DRUJ). *([Clinical Gate](https://clinicalgate.com/anatomy-and-biomechanics-of-forearm-rotation/))*

[image]

*Image source: [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Pronation_and_supination.jpg), CC licence*

During medial or lateral rotation of the upper arm (without *additional* rotation of the forearm), the humerus rotates, but the relation between the ulna and radius does not change, so there is no pronation/supination.

It is more practical to use supination/pronation for the forearm/hand, because you can have a forearm/hand in various positions where medial/lateral or internal/external does not make sense: for example, when you rotate your forearm/hand with your arm extended toward the side. Saying that, medial/lateral and internal/external rotation of the forearm is also commonly used (search: ["medial rotation of the forearm"](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&biw=1280&bih=918&ei=esBvXeCXNOSDjLsP2s2lsAU&q=%22medial%20rotation%20of%20the%20forearm%22&oq=%22medial%20rotation%20of%20the%20forearm%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30j0i30j0i5i30.18212.19047..19663...0.2..0.110.368.3j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i7i5i30.78JPF81_pcc&ved=0ahUKEwjgvIqWp7fkAhXkAWMBHdpmCVYQ4dUDCAs&uact=5)). So, you can use any of these terns according to what's more practical and less confusing in a given context.

Comment: ok, that answers for the terms supnation and pronation being forearm only. What about medial/internal and lateral/external rotation, why we don't say that of the forearm, or do we? maybe we do https://exrx.net/Articulations/Forearm

Comment: @barlop, I added that at the bottom of my answer. It's mainly to prevent confusion.

Comment: I think this line "It is more practical to use supination/pronation for the forearm/hand, because you can have a forearm/hand in various positions where medial/lateral or internal/external does not make sense: for example, when you rotate your forearm/hand with your arm extended in front of you or toward the side or placed on the table. "  <-- is incorrect, because the same applies to the upper arm , it can be out sideways, and they speak of medial and lateral there / internal and external rotation.

Comment: And your next thing "medial/lateral and internal/external rotation of the forearm is also commonly used "  is correct I think and proves that the previous thing was incorrect.

Comment: Also your last line "So, you can use any of these terns according to what's more practical and less confusing in a given context."  is I think unclear. The terms medial and lateral rotation can be applied to either. But as you showed, the terms pronation and supination only apply to the forearm

Comment: When you have your arm extended toward the side (lateral extension) and you supinate or pronate the forearm, you can't say if you medially or laterally rotated it. It is true that the same issue applies for medial/lateral rotation of the upper arm, but in this case is not really confusing. In summary: you can use all the mentioned terms for both the forearm and upper arm, except supination/pronation for the upper arm.

Comment: I think you've answered it I think I could possibly make it a bit clearer..  BTW you can say you medially or laterally rotate it because the terms apply because they're done with the human anatomy diagram of a person with arms down palms out, so you look at it from the perspective of arms down palms out when using those terms, even if the arm is out to the side.

Comment: Do you have any idea about question of mine on a similar subject? https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/52346/confusion-regarding-degrees-of-flexion-and-a-goniometer

Comment: I'll look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Supinus and pronus are latin words which mean lying face/body/palm downw and lying face/body/palm up. The hand clearly has a front and a back, and everyone knows where the back of the hand is compared to the front. It's a very clear medical word for describing the hand. Supinator and pronator muscles are also clear groups that action the hand to a prone/supine position.

If you ask which is the front and back of your forearm, not everyone will reply the same. The upper arm doesn't have a clear front and back, so it's not the best way to describe the forearm and the upper arm.